# How to redirect a joomla form (in article) to differents joomla articles?

Tags: javascript, joomla

This question is very particular to my case and I could'nt fin any solution on Joomla.org forum and others.

I have some joomla articles to display my prices table. I need several articles to display several prices (for simple coupon system).

So I have my main prices article with a COUPON field form which redirect to the prices article with discount.

```html
<form class="form-inline" name="myForm" action="/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=15&Itemid=229"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
<label for="fname">Code Promo:</label>
<input type="text" name="fname" value="PROMO2018">
<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Valider ce code">
</form>
```

If user doesn't type PROMO2018, there is an error popup. Otherwise, user is redirected by form to my other prices article with disount applied.

```js
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x != "PROMO2018") {
        alert("Le code PROMO n'est pas bon. Désolé. :-( ");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

This tiny javascript hack let me managing my sales with a simple 1 coupon system for my  product.

I would like now to work with several coupons. In fact, I need a 2nd one for another discount. So it will redirect to another joomla article prices with other prices.

So I wrote this javascript:

```js
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == "PROMO2018") {
       document = "index.php?option=com_rsform&view=rsform&formId=8&Itemid=484";
        
    }
 else
 { 
  if (x == "ETUDIANTBDX") 
  {
     location = "index.php?option=com_rsform&view=rsform&formId=4&Itemid=232";
  
  }
  else
  {
   alert("Le code PROMO n'est pas bon! Veuillez essayer un autre svp.");
   return false;
  }
 }
 
 
 

}
</script>
```

But it doesn't work! :-(

Does anyone can tell me why user is not redirected to appropriate page when submiting coupon form.

## THanks for your help.

I Follow your advice with RSFORM

And I did this code:

```html
$v_coupon = $_POST['form']['coupon'];


switch ($v_coupon) {
    case "PROMO2018":
  
        
    case "ETUDIANTBDX":
  
        echo "";
        break;
   default:
 
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Le code PROMO n'est pas bon! Veuillez essayer un autre svp.');</script>"; 
     
        break;
}
```

It works, the only problem is for default case. It doesn't show the popup error message if I type a wrong coupon code.

Comment: If using RSForm, make sure your code is setup within there:
https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/customizing-rsform-pro/css-and-javascript.html
https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/customizing-rsform-pro/custom-php-code.html

Comment: Thank you. I studied this solution, but I am not expert in coding.

Comment: I did this code:$v_coupon = $_POST['form']['coupon'];


switch ($v_coupon) {
    case "PROMO2018":
  
        
    case "ETUDIANTBDX":
  
        echo "";
        break;
   default:
 
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Le code PROMO n'est pas bon! Veuillez essayer un autre svp.');</script>"; 
     
        break;
}

Comment: I added the php RSJOOMLA code in my question. I can't disp^lay error message.

Comment: there is a much easier way.  within the field for coupon, use RSForm validation.  It will handle the error messages itself and not allow to progress till right

Comment: I liked very much this idea, but RSFORM doesn't allow this, as all the validation rules are predfined (alpha, text, email, date, etc....). The validation rules can't compare a field to several values. :-( .

Comment: You can make a new custom validation rule for it.  Then I would probably just do a in_array: https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/customizing-rsform-pro/custom-validation-rules.html

Comment: Thank you so much @YellowWebMonkey!! It works. I publish it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to my question is RSFORM with a custom validation rule.

The tutorial to create RSFORM validation rule is [here](https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/customizing-rsform-pro/custom-validation-rules.html)

The code I inserted was this one:

```html
<?php
 
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
 
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/validation.php';
 
class RSFormProCustomValidations extends RSFormProValidations
{  
 
  public static function validationTest($value, $extra = null, $data = null)
  {
    // The following makes sure the submitted value is "test"
   

if ($value == "PROMO2018") {
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
 $app->redirect('index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=165&Itemid=483');
  return true;

} elseif ($value == "ETUDIANTBDX") {
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
 $app->redirect('index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=15&Itemid=229');
  return true;
} else  {
      // Return false if the validation didn't pass.
      return false;
    }
  }
 
}
```

This simple coupon solution let me manage the sale of my products with discount.

Joomla Article=>RSformCoupon=>Joomla Article with discount=>RsformStripe=> Payment